# Prevent indexing of text loaded by javascript from XHR-ed JSON file

Tags: http-headers, seo, googlebot

I have a web document, `https://example.com/page.html`, where a javascript, like `<script src="https://example.com/script.js">` loads a `<div class="content"></div>` and into this `div` the same script loads content from a JSON file loaded by the script with `XHR`.
Now the text in the `div` is indexed by Google.

If I add to both of script and JSON file `Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex,nofollow"`, would I prevent the indexation of the text in `div` on `page.html` or not?